# UITableView not showing all sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a problem that I want to show a tableview, but separated in sections by the "status" of each item. I know how to do it with a simple string array, but I can't get to make this work with a class (Aluno) array, here's my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class DeliveriesTVC: UITableViewController {

    let sections = ["Delivered", "Not Delivered"]
    var studentList: [Array<Student>] = [[], []]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 0...5{
            studentList[0].append(Student(alunoNome: "Aluno \(i)", alunoImg: "dani_test", alunoStatus: "Delivered"))
        }

        for i in 6...10{
            studentList[1].append(Student(alunoNome: "Aluno \(i)", alunoImg: "dani_test", alunoStatus: "Not Delivered"))

        }

        self.title = "Deliveries"
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cellEntrega = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EntregaCell", for: indexPath) as? EntregaCell {

            let entregaCell = studentList[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

            // here i call a function in my TableViewCell class that update the cell itself
            cellEntrega.updateAlunoUI(Aluno: entregaCell)

            return cellEntrega

        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }


 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listaAlunos[section].count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.sections[section]
}

   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 2
   }
}
```

In the output, i just get the "first section" showing, and without a name, even with me setting the name of each section and the number of sections. I've looked everywhere but i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: You really need to get your data source figured out. Your `cellForRowAt` is based on an array of arrays named `studentList`. Your `numberOfRowsInSection` is based on an array named `listaAlunos` (perhaps a translation oversight). Your `titleForHeaderInSection` is based on another array named `sections`. And you needlessly hardcode `numberOfSections` with a value of `2`. Do not hard that number.

Comment: yeah that's an translate problem, they'r the same actually, sorry! I've also hardcoded the number of sections because i've literally tried of everything, and in the end my problem was the functions that were wrong and i didn't know. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numberOfSections` and `titleForHeader` methods are wrong, it should be

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return self.sections[section]
}
```

Additionally, you should return `self.sections.count` instead of `return 2` in `numberOfSections` being hardcoded as in case you add another object to the array, you will have to change the 2 to whatever elements the array has now.

Answer (score 0):

1. For your `numberOfSectionInTableView` function, shouldn't it be 
   `override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 2
   }` 
   with a `in` in front of the `tableView: UITableView`?
2. I don't see where you connect your `UITableView`'s `delegate` and `datasource`.

[Here](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Using-UITableView) is a tutorial to show your about using UITableView.

Take a look at "Basic Table View" - "Step 3: Set the datasource and delegate"

Comment: You don't need to set delegate and datasource in a `UITableViewController`

Comment: You are correct. somehow I thought it's in `UIViewController`.